# Is there a way to speed up the setting of multiple parameters in different bash files?

Tags: bash, terminal, editor

I'm using the SciNet computers for some simulation work, and part of this requires me to simulate data and test models using many different parameter combinations that have to be set in each bash file individually before running them through the terminal. These are just .sh files that run a .R script with certain options set, and I edit all of them using a simple text editor on Windows.

This can take a lot of time, however, if I have to specify over 100 combinations by hand in a text file. I'm wondering, is there is any way to speed up this process? Possibly a script or program that I can run to copy from one base file and make according changes to the parameters. Or if there was a way I could create a dataset and fill it with columns of parameter values that the bash file could then pull from that would be great. I haven't found anything in my search so far but I feel I may be looking in the wrong places.

Currently I can make some shortcuts by copying and pasting the files for simulations that have the most similarities between parameters, but this still requires me to go into each file manually to change the parameters that do not match.

The main body of the parameters for one setting looks as follows:

```
--studies 10 --rate 0.003 --alpha 3 --beta 3 --reps 10 --mc 500 --job ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} --out /Results
```

Comment: How about adding groups of variables to another bash file in the form of param=value and running source./your_vars_file.sh? Your script can use preset system variables from this source file after that. Actually, this param=value in files can be generated from any data sources.

Comment: This sounds like it should be pretty easy, but without knowing more about how the parameters are organized and used it's hard to be specific. Are they all in one shell script file, scattered across multiple files, or something else? If there are multiple scripts, how do they interact with each other (e.g. is there one master script that runs the others, or ...)?

Comment: @Siarhej What would this involve? Creating a .sh file with rows of all parameter settings in the same order? I'm quite new to this topic so some of the terminology is confusing here.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Each bash file I create contains specific parameters to be used in data generation and model building. I run an R script and then input the line of parameters above after it, which then sets these in the script. So for each setting I need to change one or more of these parameters.
There isn't any interaction between the shell script files, they are all essentially copies of one another with just some parameter values changed.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. When you say you input the line of parameters, do you mean that you type (or paste) in the parameters, or that the shell script does that part for you? And when you say that "sets these in the script", do you mean that it's setting them in the R script, or that the R script is setting them in the shell script? I need to understand the information flow here.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Sorry for the confusion. By input, yes I type the parameters by hand into each shell script separately, by editing them in a text file. And by 'set in script', I meant that by running the .sh file it runs the R script with the parameters I specify.

Comment: how are the `100 combinations` determined? are you talking about ***all*** combinations of a given set of inputs, eg, *`all combinations of {1,2,3} / {a,b,c} / {X,Y,Z}`* or are the 100 combinations (effectively) randomly chosen? if the former then a (relatively) simple script could auto-generate the combinations and store in a file

Answer (score 1):

The way you described the problem is confusing.  Hence, the number of comments.

The below script is what I visualized to be the issue you are grappling with. Namely,

- codifying scenario parameters, and
- looping using those parameters.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DBG=0

COMMAND_ROOT="something_mix_of_command_and_shared_parameters"

###
### Defining Scenario Parameters
###
rates=( 0.001 0.002 0.003 0.004 0.005 )
alphas=( 1 2 3 )
betas=( 1 2 3 )
reps=( 5 10 20 50 100 )
mcs=( 400 450 500 550 600 )

###
### Looping on parameters for "test" plan
###
for rate in ${rates[@]}
do
    test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\t [rate= ${rate}] ..."
    for alpha in ${alphas[@]}
    do
        test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\t\t [alpha= ${alpha}] ..."
        for beta in ${betas[@]}
        do
            test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\t\t\t [beta= ${beta}] ..."
            for rep in ${reps[@]}
            do
                test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\t\t\t\t [rep= ${rep}] ..."
                for mc in ${mcs[@]}
                do
                    test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\t\t\t\t\t [mc= ${mc}] ..."
                    SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID="${some_unique_identifier}"

                    COMMAND_PARAMETERS="\
                    --studies 10 \
                    --rate ${rate} \
                    --alpha ${alpha} \
                    --beta ${beta} \
                    --reps ${rep} \
                    --mc ${mc} \
                    --job ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} --out /Results"

                    echo -e " Running permutation [${rate}|${alpha}|${beta}|${rep}|${mc}] ..."

                    #${COMMAND_ROOT} ${COMMAND_PARAMETERS}
                done
                echo ""
            done
        done
    done
done
exit
```